# SQL Complex Transformation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the bellow, what I want is that any Person who move GP due to change of address should have the start date and end date in the period. However the end date will be a date less than the next start date. Please how do I write this query?

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(Local_Patient_Identifier VARCHAR(70),    
    NHS_Number VARCHAR(70), GMP VARCHAR(70), Practice_Code_GP VARCHAR(70),  CDS_Date DATE)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES
('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G111111',  'N77777',   '2016-05-23'),
('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G222222',  'N77777',   '2016-06-13'),
('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G222222',  'N77777',   '2016-06-13'),
('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-02-09'),
('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-03-06'),
('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-03-15'),
('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-03-29'),
('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-05-10'),
('A111111112',  '8BFD002',  'G3333332', 'JJ44444',  '2015-05-21'),
('A111111112',  '8BFD002',  'G3333332', 'KK44445',  '2016-05-02'),
('A111111112',  '8BFD002',  'G3333332', 'WW44444',  '2017-02-13')
SELECT*FROM @Tab
```

Expected OUTPUT
[image]

Comment: What happens to 4th row to 8th row? Why those rows are not part of output?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy whenever a person change GP they all change. The current GP end date will be null.The GP is the GMP column

Comment: So if `GMP` changes OR `Practice_code_GP changes`, that should trigger a new period?

Comment: @Xedni That is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_Number to get this results:

```
;With Cte as (
    Select *,JoinKey = Row_Number() over(partition by Local_Patient_Identifier order by CDS_Date) from (
        Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over(partition by Local_patient_Identifier, GMP, Practice_Code_GP order by CDS_Date) 
            from #tab
        ) a
    where a.RowN = 1
)
Select c1.Local_Patient_Identifier,c1.NHS_Number, c1.GMP, c1.Practice_Code_GP, c1.CDS_Date as StartDate, 
    Dateadd(day, -1 , c2.CDS_Date) as EndDate from cte c1 left join cte c2
on c1.Local_Patient_Identifier = c2.Local_Patient_Identifier
and c1.JoinKey = c2.JoinKey - 1
```

Output as below:

```
+--------------------------+------------+----------+------------------+------------+------------+
| Local_Patient_Identifier | NHS_Number |   GMP    | Practice_Code_GP | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+------------------+------------+------------+
| A111111111               | 8BFD000    | G111111  | N77777           | 2016-05-23 | 2016-06-12 |
| A111111111               | 8BFD000    | G222222  | N77777           | 2016-06-13 | 2017-02-08 |
| A111111111               | 8BFD000    | G3333333 | ZZ44444          | 2017-02-09 | NULL       |
| A111111112               | 8BFD002    | G3333332 | JJ44444          | 2015-05-21 | 2016-05-01 |
| A111111112               | 8BFD002    | G3333332 | KK44445          | 2016-05-02 | 2017-02-12 |
| A111111112               | 8BFD002    | G3333332 | WW44444          | 2017-02-13 | NULL       |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+------------------+------------+------------+
```

You can use windowing function lead if you are using SQL Server >= 2012

Comment: As a general rule, you'd want to avoid referencing a CTE more than once. The reason is that the code within the CTE will be executed each time it's referenced. Better to "cache" the cte results to a #TempTable or @TableVariable and then reference that multiple times...

Comment: I differ with this idea... Again it depends on volume of data selected as part of CTE... Reason is that CTE internally stores in-memory without statistics... If it goes outside of limited in-memory it will spill over to tempdb by default without statistics. If volume is minimal when compared to allocated max-memory size I still prefer to go to CTE... If large volume of records then we can go for temp tables

Comment: You can differ all you want, it doesn't make it less true. If the CTE is the most expensive part of the query (and, in this case it is, it is because of the sort), you incur that cost every time the CTE is referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I wenta bout it. I renamed the columns while I was working on it because I got tired of typing long names, but I've aliased them on the way out closer to what you expected. I also converted the output dates using British date formatting (dd/mm/yyyy) to match your output

```
declare @tab table
(
    LPI varchar(70),    
    NHSNum varchar(70), 
    GMP varchar(70), 
    GP varchar(70),  
    CDSDate date
)
insert into @Tab 
values
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G111111',  'N77777',   '2016-05-23'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G222222',  'N77777',   '2016-06-13'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G222222',  'N77777',   '2016-06-13'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-02-09'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-03-06'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-03-15'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-03-29'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-05-10'),
    ('A111111112',  '8BFD002',  'G3333332', 'JJ44444',  '2015-05-21'),
    ('A111111112',  '8BFD002',  'G3333332', 'KK44445',  '2016-05-02'),
    ('A111111112',  '8BFD002',  'G3333332', 'WW44444',  '2017-02-13')


;with src as
(
    select 
        RID = row_number() over (partition by LPI, NHSNum order by min(CDSDate)),    
        LPI, 
        NHSNum, 
        GMP, 
        GP,
        MinDate = min(CDSDate)
    from @tab
    group by     
        LPI, 
        NHSNum, 
        GMP, 
        GP
)
select 
    LocalPatientIdentifier = a.LPI,
    NHSNumber = a.NHSNum,
    GMP = a.GMP,
    PracticeCodeGP = a.GP,
    StartDate = convert(varchar(50), a.MinDate, 103),
    EndDate = convert(varchar(50), dateadd(day, -1, b.MinDate), 103)
from src a
left outer join src b
    on a.LPI = b.LPI
        and a.NHSNum = b.NHSNum
        and a.RID = b.RID - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should be good for SQL Server 2008R2...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tab', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Tab;

CREATE TABLE #Tab (
    Local_Patient_Identifier VARCHAR(70),    
    NHS_Number VARCHAR(70), 
    GMP VARCHAR(70), 
    Practice_Code_GP VARCHAR(70),  
    CDS_Date DATE
    );
INSERT #Tab (Local_Patient_Identifier, NHS_Number, GMP, Practice_Code_GP, CDS_Date) VALUES
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G111111',  'N77777',   '2016-05-23'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G222222',  'N77777',   '2016-06-13'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G222222',  'N77777',   '2016-06-13'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-02-09'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-03-06'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-03-15'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-03-29'),
    ('A111111111',  '8BFD000',  'G3333333', 'ZZ44444',  '2017-05-10'),
    ('A111111112',  '8BFD002',  'G3333332', 'JJ44444',  '2015-05-21'),
    ('A111111112',  '8BFD002',  'G3333332', 'KK44445',  '2016-05-02'),
    ('A111111112',  '8BFD002',  'G3333332', 'WW44444',  '2017-02-13');

--  SELECT * FROM #Tab t

--======================================================================

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ChangeData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #ChangeData;

WITH 
    cte_AddRN AS (
        SELECT 
            t.Local_Patient_Identifier,
            t.NHS_Number,
            t.GMP,
            t.Practice_Code_GP,
            t.CDS_Date,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Local_Patient_Identifier, t.GMP, t.Practice_Code_GP ORDER BY t.CDS_Date)
        FROM 
            #Tab t
        )
SELECT 
    ar.Local_Patient_Identifier,
    ar.NHS_Number,
    ar.GMP,
    ar.Practice_Code_GP,
    ar.CDS_Date,
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ar.Local_Patient_Identifier ORDER BY ar.CDS_Date)
    INTO #ChangeData
FROM 
    cte_AddRN ar
WHERE 
    ar.RN = 1;

--  SELECT * FROM #ChangeData cd

SELECT
    cd1.Local_Patient_Identifier,
    cd1.NHS_Number,
    cd1.GMP,
    cd1.Practice_Code_GP,
    StartDate = cd1.CDS_Date,   
    EndDate = cd2.CDS_Date
FROM
    #ChangeData cd1
    LEFT JOIN #ChangeData cd2
        ON cd1.Local_Patient_Identifier = cd2.Local_Patient_Identifier
        AND cd1.RN = cd2.RN - 1;
```

Results...

```
Local_Patient_Identifier    NHS_Number  GMP         Practice_Code_GP    StartDate  EndDate
------------------------    ----------  --------    ----------------    ---------- ----------
A111111111                  8BFD000     G111111     N77777              2016-05-23 2016-06-13
A111111111                  8BFD000     G222222     N77777              2016-06-13 2017-02-09
A111111111                  8BFD000     G3333333    ZZ44444             2017-02-09 NULL
A111111112                  8BFD002     G3333332    JJ44444             2015-05-21 2016-05-02
A111111112                  8BFD002     G3333332    KK44445             2016-05-02 2017-02-13
A111111112                  8BFD002     G3333332    WW44444             2017-02-13 NULL
```